# How to implement Android Image Slider like this?

Tags: android, image, view, slider, flipper

I need to implement [Android Image Slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D41yf.png) exactly like this. lend me some suggestions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called Carousels.
You can get references from below:

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3991

https://github.com/Azoft/CarouselLayoutManager

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3712

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a class that is responsible of displaying the images.  The class should have its onSwipeTouchListener and load images to memory and move them right and left according to the gesture.  But don't load all images at once! Load the previous and next 5 images for example and have a single filler image in memory for the rest.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But Is there any library to implement this image slider? I'm new to Android Development this looks quite bit complicated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this can help too:

https://www.sitepoint.com/handling-displaying-images-android/

Comment: That helped me a lot. Thank you.

Comment: @MohamedSadakathulla Glad I could help:)